# ¿Qué significa "nadie pela la plata a los dientes"?

Tags: méxico, expresiones

Me dicen que "nadie pela la plata a los dientes" es una expresión mexicana pero no sé que significa. ¿Me podrían por favor explicar su significado?

Comment: Extra expresión es claramente regional. He estado buscando y no aparece nada de información.

Comment: Me parece que sólo está en la canción del _Señor de los Cielos_, pero sin la "a": _nadie pela la plata los dientes_. "Pelar los dientes" es mostrar los dientes: sonreir, coquetear y también amenazar. La "plata" es el dinero. Entonces podría ser algo así: "nadie hace ostentación de su dinero y su poder [como el Señor de los Cielos]". Pero tendría que confirmarlo un mexicano.

Comment: Yo creo que dice "nadie pela a la plata los dientes como lo hace el señor de los cielos..", lo cual es el equivalente exacto de "nadie pela los dientes a la plata como lo hace el señor de los cielos... " Sólamente se utilizó esa estructura gramatical un tanto extraña para que "encajara" en la canción. Es la única forma en que le puedo encontrar alguna explicación. Como bien menciona @Rodrigo, "pelar los dientes" en este caso se entendería que "nadie le coquetea al dinero como lo hace el señor de los cielos", en otras palabras, a nadie le sonríe tanto la fortuna(en términos de dinero) como a él

Answer (score 5):

El verbo pelar (descubrir, desnudar, despejar, despojar, mondar)  en el lenguaje coloquial, significa mostrar, enseñar o exponer. El dicho "**nadie pela la plata y los dientes**" significa que si se enseña el dinero no hay necesidad de enseñar los dientes o, lo que es lo mismo, si pagas no tienes que pelear y viceversa. Si no se enseña la plata habrá que enseñar los dientes. El dicho implica que no es necesario mostrar ambas cosas al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Pelar es enseñar. Nadie pela (enseña) la plata (el dinero) y los dientes como lo hace el señor de los cielos.

Si enseñas el dinero no necesitas enseñar los dientes, o sea, pelear.